# JQuery Ajax function called twice whereas first call was okay

Tags: jquery, timer

First of all I'd like to precise that I've read all the "jQuery called twice" suggestions in this website, and none of them had the problem I'm facing.

It's so simple that I don't understand how comes it behaves like this.

- I first call once and AJAX request that loads 20 records and put them in a table
- then in those <tr> I add one (yet) picture, and I assign events like this :

:

```
$('.moderation_ok').click(function() {
  return decisionOk($(this));
});
```

then

```
function decisionBoutonOk(t) {
  var p=t.parent().parent().parent().parent();
  var id=p.attr('id').substring(3);
  AjaxDevisSendDecision(id, 1, null);
  return false;
}
```

and in the Ajax function, if everything went fine I read the result where there is *another* row to add:

```
function AjaxDevisSendDecision(id, decision, raison) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/json/devis/decision/',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data : { id: id, decision: decision, raison: raison },
    context: this,
    cache: false,
  })
  .success( function (data) {
    if (data.success) {
      /* Success */
      for (var x in data.result) {
        var s=data.result[x];
        addRowIntoTable(s);
        refreshEvents();
      }
    }
  });
}
```

The problem I'm facing is the first call is perfect and works perfectly: click => call AJAX => result of AJAX call ok => add new row...

And now I'm stuck: if I click on the image of the second row, the AjaxDevisSendDecision() is called **instantaneously** *twice*. And really don't understand what's going on.

Any idea?

Edit: if there's an exception in the event handler there's no problem anymore:

```
function decisionBoutonOk(t) {
  var p=t.parent().parent().parent().parent();
  var id=p.attr('id').substring(3);
  p.css({ backgroundColor: '#5f5' });
  p.stop(true,true).hide('slow');
  AjaxDevisSendDecision(id, 2, null);
  eeqsf(); /* unknown function = raise exception */
  return false;
}
```

maybe this could give a clue to understand what's going on...

For your information, here's almost the whole source code:

```
function refreshEvents() {
  $('tr').each(function() {
    var id=$(this).attr('id').substring(3);
    if(typeof(globT[id].height)!='undefined') {
      return;
    }
    /* First time here = remember height in pixels */
    globT[id].height=$(this).children('.principal').children('.texte').height();
    $(this).children('.principal').children('.texte').height('89px');
    $(this)
      .mouseenter(function() {
        var id=$(this).attr('id').substring(3);
        var c=$(this).children('.principal').children('.texte');
        c.stop(true, true).animate({ height: globT[id].height+'px'}, 'slow');
        c.children('.choix_moderateur').stop(true, true).fadeIn('slow');
      })
      .mouseleave(function() {
        var c=$(this).children('.principal').children('.texte');
        c.stop(true, true).animate({ height: '89px'}, 'slow');
        c.children('.choix_moderateur').stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow');
        c.children('.raison_refus').stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow');
      });
  });
  $('.moderation_ok').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return decisionBoutonOk($(this));
  });
}

function decisionBoutonOk(t) {
  var p=t.parent().parent().parent().parent();
  var id=p.attr('id').substring(3);
  AjaxDevisSendDecision(id, 1,null);
  eeqsf();
  return false;
}

function AjaxDevisGet(nb, notassigned) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/json/devis/liste/',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data : { nb: nb, notassigned: notassigned },
    context: this,
    success: function (data) {
      if (data.success) {
        for (var x in data.result) {
          var s=data.result[x];
          ajouteDevisDansDOM(s);
        }
        refreshEvents();
      }
    }
  });
}

function AjaxDevisSendDecision(id, decision, raison) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/json/devis/decision/',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data : { id: id, decision: decision, raison: raison },
    context: this,
    cache: false,
  })
  .success( function (data) {
    if (data.success) {
      /* success=add each row in the result */
      for (var x in data.result) {
        var s=data.result[x];
        ajouteDevisDansDOM(s);
        refreshEvents();
      }
    }
  })
  .complete( function () {
    console.log('complete');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was here:

```
function refreshEvents() {
  $('tr').each(function() {
    ...
    blabla
    ...
  });
  $('.moderation_ok').click(function(event) {
    ...
    blabla
    ...
  });
}
```

After a successful Ajax call, I called `refreshEvents()` and in this function (see before) I **always** called `$('.moderation_ok').click(function(event) {}`. This meant: "add **another** function if we click on all the elements that belong to the class `moderation_ok`.

I thought that when declaring functions like `$('.moderation_ok').click(function(event) {}` it overrides the click() behavior.
Nope!
I'm not deleting my question because my answer may be useful to others.

Here's the code I added *before*:

```
$('.moderation_ok').unbind('click');
```

And now it works like a charm.

### So, summary:

When declaring functions like `$('.moderation_ok').click(function(event) {}` jQuery **adds** this function the click() behavior. If you do *twice* this, the function will be called *twice* and so on.

In this case, use `unbind()` to remove any event handler: `$('.moderation_ok').unbind('click');`